# How to Read posted file contents in WEB API - httpRequest.Files

Tags: c#, excel, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a HttpPost method in my web api which is accepting a csv file from a client.

I am trying to read the csv file contents in memory but not getting any luck with this.

The System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString is not returning the actual content of the file.

Here is my code;

```
               var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;

                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream);
                    byte[] byteArray = binReader.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);

                    var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray);

                }
```

Here are the contents of posted file;

[image]

Comment: If it's textual why are you using a ``BinaryReader`` to read the ``InputStream``? 
You could use ``StringReader`` or ``StreamReader`` instead.

What do you see instead of the contents?

Comment: `xlsx` is a complex binary format, how do you know it's not correct?